# cannot get label center when overiding default TextField height

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I was asked to decrease the size of the MUI Component TextField by 4px. I did this by manipulating the the root & .MuiOutlinedInput-input. It adjusted the height but now my label (Email) is not centered vertically. I tried adding this to the sx:

```
.MuiInputLabel-outlined": transform: "translateY(-50%)"
```

but it drove the label out of the input field and to the left. Is there a better way to do this? My code is located below with just the TextField height adjusted and no translateY implemented. It is also worth noting that I have not touched the Password TextField yet.

```
<Box sx={{marginTop: "3rem"}}> 
    <TextField type="Email"
               label="Email"
               variant="outlined"
               value={loginEmail ? loginEmail : ""}
               name="Email"
               onChange={(e) => {
                   setloginEmail(e.target.value);
               }}
               sx={{
                  width: "100%",
                  maxWidth: "400px",
                  marginBottom: "0.5rem",
                  background: "transparent",
                  borderColor: "#ccc", // Set a lighter border color
                  color: "#aaa", // Set a lighter label text color
               "& .MuiInputLabel-outlined": {
                color: "#aaa !important", // Set a lighter label outline color
              },
              "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
                borderColor: "#ccc",
              },
              "& .MuiOutlinedInput-input": {
                color: "#aaa", // Set a lighter input text color
                height:17
              },
              "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
                borderColor: "#946bde",
                
              },
             
            }}
            inputProps={{
              style: {
                color: "#aaa", // Set a lighter input text color
              },
            }}
          />
          
          <TextField
            label="Password"
            type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
            variant="outlined"
            value={loginPassword ? loginPassword : ""}
            name="password"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setLoginPassword(e.target.value);
            }}
            InputProps={{
              endAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="end">
                  <IconButton
                    onClick={() => setShowPassword(!showPassword)}
                    onMouseDown={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                    edge="end"
                    style={{ color: "#aaa" }}
                    
                    sx={{
                      
                      
                      transform: 'translateY(-17%)',
                      
                    }}
                  >
                    {showPassword ? <VisibilityOffOutlinedIcon /> : <VisibilityOutlinedIcon />}
                  </IconButton>
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
            }}
            sx={{
              width: "100%",
              marginTop: "2rem",
              maxWidth: "400px",
              marginBottom: "0.5rem",
              background: "transparent",
              borderColor: "#ccc", // Set a lighter border color
              color: "#aaa", // Set a lighter label text color
              "& .MuiInputLabel-outlined": {
                color: "#aaa !important", // Set a lighter label outline color
              },
              "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
                borderColor: "#ccc",
              },
              "& .MuiOutlinedInput-input": {
                color: "#aaa", // Set a lighter input text color
              },
              "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
                borderColor: "#946bde",
              },
            }}
            inputProps={{
              style: {
                color: "#aaa", // Set a lighter input text color
              },
            }}
          />
        </Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

ended up using the size prop:```<TextField
type="Email"

```
            label="Email"
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            value={loginEmail ? loginEmail : ""}
            name="Email"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setloginEmail(e.target.value);
            }}
            sx={{...............rest of code
```